The vue2 project started with sass keeps reporting errors scss file parsing error: SassError:
`After upgrading webpack4 of vue2 project to webpack5, replace node-sass with sass, and then start up for a long time, scss parsing error is displayed, complete error:
enter image description here
I updated the configuration of the.babelrc file, the reference configuration and order of the loader, updated the version of the related dependencies, but it still does not solve the problem.The configuration is as follows:
.babelrc ：
enter image description here
webpack.conf.js:
enter image description here
"
